# IC for translating 5V to 1.8V I2C signals

Tags: i2c, level-shifting

Looking for an IC to translate between 5V and 1.8V I2C. I need to connect an I2C sensor with MCU. MCU I2C pins are pulled-up to 5V while the maximum voltage on the sensor's I2C pins is 1.8V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 2 NMOS for bidirectional levelshifting of I2C. The cathode of the integrated body diode should point towards the higher voltage. The source of the NMOS should be connected to the lower voltage.

Make sure you pick a NMOS that has low-enough V_GS threshold and low-enough gate capacitance. For your application i would recommend a SSM6N37FU or a similar part.

[image: LTSpice Schematic of levelshifting circuit with 2 NMOS]

Comment: `Make sure you pick a NMOS that has low-enough V_GS threshold and low-enough gate capacitance.` and low enough output capacitance (Coss) to cause minimal distortion on the signals. Because the output capacitance of each MOSFET will be in parallel with each line's capacitance (parasitic + IC input), and these capacitances will interact with the pull-up resistors to form RC filters.

Comment: ah, well, silly me, C_oss was exactly was i meant

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. Don't understand why moderators close this type of questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [TXS0102](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0102.pdf?ts=1679409934312&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) for a plug-and-play IC and read this great [Application Note](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf) from Phillips on the topic